# submitting form using javascript, saving it to $_POST

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an a tag to submit a form but the PHP doesn't seem to react:

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    echo 'dog';
else
    echo 'cat';
$currentPage = 'test';
echo <<<eod
<form method='post' action='$currentPage.php' id='sign_in' style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' style='width: 90px;'>
Password: <input type='text' name='password' style='width: 90px; border-right: 1px solid #bbb'>
<a id='sign_in_submit' name='submit'>Sign in</a>
</form>
eod;
?>
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('sign_in');

    document.getElementById("sign_in_submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
        form.submit();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

tried three methods of submission via JS but none of them seem to work

Comment: What does "but the PHP doesn't seem to react" mean?

Comment: Have you tried checking `$_POST['username']` or `$_POST['password']` instead? `<a>` tags don't have `name`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your submit `a` tag would not be included in the post data, so check for the existence of one of the input tags, say `$_POST['username']`

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your code. You are checking if submit field/button is sent over the form, but you do not have anything named submit in your form. You have got username and password, so changing your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to `if(isset($_POST['username']))` or `if(isset($_POST))` will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

try in javascript this:

```
document.sign_in.submit();
```

and make a submit button like this

```
<input type="submit" id='sign_in_submit' value="Sign in" name='submit'
```